# Unable to install OpenVas in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, openvas

While installing OpenVAS vulnerability assessment suite from the software center I am getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

openvas: Depends: openvas-libraries but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: greenbone-security-desktop but it is not going to be installed
```

What might be the problem?  What should I do install it?

Comment: Where are you getting openvas from?

Comment: software center

Comment: broken dependency tree from adding ppas or other repositories like kali.  openvas installs fine from software center on mainline with the pirho ppa installed(not sure on virgin mainline, but i suspect you're trying to pull in kali packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that you are trying to install a virtual packages that is confusing apt. Also, you must make sure that you have the **universe** repository is activated:

```
$ grep universe /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ precise main universe
```

The first command should return you something like that, if it don't you should add the repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb $(grep main /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -m1 http | gawk -F ' ' '{print $2}') universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once this is done, if you want the client:

```
sudo apt-get install openvas-client=2.0.3-4
```

This has no problem whatsoever in the [packages page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openvas-client).

But if what you want is the server:

```
sudo apt-get install openvas-server=2.0.3-4
```

Again, this has no problem whatsoever in the [packages page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openvas-server).

Answer (score -1):

Try installing using the command line. The following guide (from the OpenVAS site) should assist you with this, but it's based on Debian and not Ubuntu (which is merely an Ubuntu derivative) so I would recommend further reading: 

http://www.openvas.org/install-packages.html#openvas_debian_obs

You could also see the following blog post which explains, in detail, how to install the latest version of OpenVAS on Ubuntu 12.04:
http://samiux.blogspot.com/2013/05/howto-openvas-on-ubuntu-desktop-1204-lts.html

The software center is great for simple, single purpose applications like games and a simple text editor or some other tool, but if you start fiddling with things like OpenVAS which have more complex installations and a myriad of installation options it's often better to use the command line.

Comment: The following error came up:                                                           The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsd : Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.